# Need to execute the 'retry' keyword limited number of times

Tags: ruby

consider the block below

```
  begin
    #something
  rescue
    retry
  end
```

I need to execute this retry operation only 5 times, how would I change the above code? If 5 times exceeds,then it needs to come out of the begin block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a variable to keep track of the number of times that you've retried:

```
retryCount = 5
begin
  #something
rescue
  retryCount -= 1
  if retryCount > 0
    retry
  end
end
```

Comment: Why didn't you follow the convention of using snake-case for variable names (e.g. `retry_count`)?

Comment: Well I followed another convention. Also this does not affect the essence of the answer too much, I hope you agree